# Array Formula for a specific cell range that is expanding to an unknown length

Tags: google-sheets-api

I'm trying to perform an `ARRAYFORMULA` starting from a specific cell (K10 - first row of a specific section shown in green in the image) to an unknown end.  I basically have the ability to keep adding rows of data in this section so it could end at K15 or K300, it's an unknown quantity.

Also, the section below it needs the same treatment (shown in red in the image), but its starting cell will also change dynamically due to the above.

[image]